# Joining to the users table via an intermediary table for custom Views

Tags: views

I'm making a custom module that needs Views (API 3) integration. I have a table `gentle_teams_season` that can join to a table `gentle_teams_season_users` which then joins to the users table.

This is my `gentle_teams_season` table:

```
id      int
begin   int
end     int
```

This is my `gentle_teams_season_users` table:

```
uid    int    (foreign key to users table)
sid    int    (foreign key to gentle_teams_season table)
```

I want to be able to link a user to a season, but in an n-n relationship (a user can have multiple seasons, a season can have multiple users).

How can I get the users to show up when I'm making a View starting from Seasons?

This is the join I've tried (along with some others), which makes sense to me, but doesn't work. So what am I missing?

```
$data['gentle_teams_season']['table']['join'] = array(
  'users' => array(
    'left_table' => 'gentle_teams_season_users',
    'left_field' => 'sid',
    'field' => 'sid'
  )
);

$data['gentle_teams_season_users']['table']['join'] = array(
  'users' => array(
    'left_field' => 'uid',
    'field' => 'uid'
  )
);
```

I believe I'm joining from the seasons_users table to the users, via the intermediary table and then telling the Views API how to join from the intermediary table to the users table. I found that [here](http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/views-2-table-aliases-and-extra-criteria/).

My entire `hook_views_data` can be found in my GitHub repository, at the bottom of [this file](https://github.com/petermorlion/GentleTeams/blob/master/gentle_teams/gentle_teams.module). I couldn't get the include (.inc file) to work, unfortunately.

This is my `hook_views_data`:

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_views_data()
*/
function gentle_teams_views_data() {
  //watchdog('gentle_teams', 'views data requested');

  /*
   * The seasons
   */
  $data['gentle_teams_season']['table']['group'] = t('Gentle teams');

  $data['gentle_teams_season']['table']['base'] = array(
    'field' => 'id',
    'title' => t('Gentle seasons'),
    'help' => t('Seasons as defined for Gentle Ultimate.'),
    'weight' => -10,
  );

  $data['gentle_teams_season']['id'] = array(
    'title' => t('Season id'),
    'help' => t('The season id'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
      'click_sortable' => TRUE
    ),
    'sort' => array('handler' => 'views_handler_sort'),
  );

  $data['gentle_teams_season']['begin'] = array(
    'title' => t('Begin'),
    'help' => t('The start year of the season'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
      'click_sortable' => TRUE
    ),
    'sort' => array('handler' => 'views_handler_sort'),
  );

  $data['gentle_teams_season']['end'] = array(
    'title' => t('End'),
    'help' => t('The end year of the season'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
      'click_sortable' => TRUE
    ),
    'sort' => array('handler' => 'views_handler_sort'),
  );

  $data['gentle_teams_season']['table']['join'] = array(
    'users' => array(
      'left_table' => 'gentle_teams_season_users',
      'left_field' => 'sid',
      'field' => 'sid'
    )
  );

  $data['gentle_teams_season_users']['table']['join'] = array(
    'users' => array(
      'left_field' => 'uid',
      'field' => 'uid'
    )
  );

  /*
   * The teams
   */
  $data['gentle_teams_team']['table']['group'] = t('Gentle teams');

  $data['gentle_teams_team']['table']['base'] = array(
    'field' => 'id',
    'title' => t('Gentle teams'),
    'help' => t('Teams as defined for Gentle Ultimate.'),
    'weight' => -10,
  );

  $data['gentle_teams_team']['table']['join'] = array(
    'gentle_teams_season' => array(
      'left_field' => 'id',
      'field' => 'sid'
    )
  );

  $data['gentle_teams_team']['id'] = array(
    'title' => t('Team id'),
    'help' => t('The team id'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
      'click_sortable' => TRUE
    ),
    'sort' => array('handler' => 'views_handler_sort'),
  );

  $data['gentle_teams_team']['name'] = array(
    'title' => t('Name'),
    'help' => t('The name of the team'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
      'click_sortable' => TRUE
    ),
    'sort' => array('handler' => 'views_handler_sort'),
  );



  return $data;
}
```

Comment: what is the structure of you custom table ? what version of views are you using ? and what's the rest of your implementation of hook_views_data like ?

Comment: Edited my question to provide more info.